# rails 3 relationship scopes 3 levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

These are my model relationships:

```
User
has_many :book_offers
has_and_belongs_to_many :books

BookOffer
has_and_belongs_to_many :books
belongs_to :user

Book
has_and_belongs_to_many :book_offers
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Here are the scopes I'm using:

```
User
scope :current_users, lambda {
  joins(:book_offers) & BookOffer.current_offers.
  order("user.company_name ASC")
}

BookOffer
scope :current_offers, lambda {
joins(:books) & Book.current_books
}

Book
scope :current_books, lambda { where("ending_date > ? && beginning_date < ?", Time.now, Time.now).order("beginning_date DESC") }
```

What I'm trying to do is get an array of users who have offers in the current books.
I also need to make it so that users with the same company name only show up once in the list even though they are separate user entries.

I am not sure if I need to be using has many through in this case. But I'm been wrestling with this for a while and need some guidance.

Thanks